# Flash that display:none/$(div).hide; a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript

I have made a hidden DIV containing a flash-movie, and a button which display the layer. When the Flash is finished, I would like it to hide the DIV again.

**Flash CS4 AS2.0**

I couldn't find any solution on the web that does it. Does any of you know where, or know a solution?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Are you the author of the flash movie?  (Would you be able to alter the Flash to make a javascript call?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class to call Javascript that hides your div.

Comment: I think it will work. Flash used to use fscommand(), so if ExternalInterface doesn't work in your project you can try that. Warning: it's ugly! :)

Comment: I can't seem to find out... The example page on the link you provided, isn't working... :-/